# an SQL Search query using more than one condition

Tags: c#, sql, where-clause, sqlparameter

my problem is that , i made a child form for searching , but i have problem in sql query and parameters , my code is

```
SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(
    "Data Source=MOHAMMED-PC;Initial Catalog=salessystem;Integrated Security=True");

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
    "Select * from customers WHERE (docno = @doc) OR (NAME LIKE @name ) OR (salepoint = @salepoint)", sc);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doc", doctxt.Text);
command.Parameters.Addwithvalue("@name", nametxt.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salepoint", salepointtxt.Text);
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command, sc);
sda.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

i have error in sql adapter command and in where clause command , any help ??

Comment: Please can you post the error message?

Comment: What about checking data types, too. All test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three  things:

1. You have a typo on this line

   ```
   command.Parameters.Addwithvalue("@name", nametxt.Text);
   ```

   The method is `AddWithValue` (note the case difference)
2. The [constructor of `SqlDataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awzk4kc1.aspx) takes the command but no connection then since the command already contains the connection, so this is correct:

   ```
   SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
   ```

   Probably the most important last:
3. If you use `LIKE` you need to use the wild-cards `%`:

   ```
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", string.Format("%{0}%",nametxt.Text);
   ```

Comment: Makes you wonder if this is even the code that gave the OP an error.

Comment: @ryadavilli: At least these are two compile time errors and he mentioned two errors(one at the "adapter command").

Comment: He should also not get any results from the LIKE clause where is he using the SQL `%` Wild card..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Yes, you're right. Edited my answer accordingly. Do you know how to format my answerso that the numbers are consecutively?

Comment: i change the sql adapter command and i use the wild-cards , and its works fine,   thank u very much